# can not selected python packages for newly created environment in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

i am new to anaconda. after installing anaconda-3, i wanted to create an environment via anaconda navigator.however, the check-box that allows one to choose python packages is never active.
i installed Anaconda in the same directory where my python apps/project are.

please let me know how to be able to select python packages when creating new environment

**image**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First thing you do is check for updates in your Anaconda. If available, do that.
2. If it still doesn't work, create env from command prompt instead, using the command

   ```
   conda create --name xyz_env python=3.8
   ```
3. If it says SSL error set verify to False. Use command

   ```
   conda config --set ssl_verify False
   ```

   Now, create your env, using command

   ```
   conda create --name xyz_env python=3.8
   ```